# Regex two optional groups, but not just the first group

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want a regex that will capture words with two optional prefixes, but not the first one alone. I'm using Python 3.6.
It should capture

```
cat
nicecat
bigcat
```

and any prefixes before those two, like

```
supernicecat
fatbigcat
```

but it should NOT capture

```
fatcat
supercat
xyzcat
```

Here's what I have so far. It's not quite working.

```
\b(\w+)?(?:big|nice)?cat\b
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap them in another group:

```
\b(?:(\w+)?(?:big|nice))?cat\b
```

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/rMUsNu/1)

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
\b(?:\w*?(?:big|nice))?cat\b
```

Put the \w* into the optional group.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
^(?:[a-z]*(?:big|nice))?cat$
```

Be sure to enable multi-line flag. I am assuming each entry is on its own line.

The problem with your Regex is that you made `big|nice` **or nothing** due to the question mark. What I am proposing is to add `[a-z]*` before it then add a question mark over `(?:[a-z]*(?:big|nice))` expression in order to allow standalone `cat` to match.